# Get last n bits of binary

Tags: c++

I am working on a project and what I need is getting the last `n` bits of a binary. I tried something but I doesn't work very well. This is the code :

```
long long int to_bin(int n)
{
     long long int Fin=0,pow=1;
     while(n)
     {
       Fin=Fin+(n%2)*pow;
       n/=2;pow*=10;
     }
 return Fin;
}           // returns binary 

int get_last_n_digits(int nr , int n_dig)
{
    int l_digits =0 , power = 1;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n_dig ; i++)
            power *=10;
        l_digits = nr%power;
    return l_digits;
}         //returns last digits of a number
```

And for example, I need the last 2 bits of the binary representation of 245, ie something like this :

```
get_last_n_digits(to_bin(254,S) ;
```

and the result is : 4 ;
What's wrong ?

Comment: Read about bitwise AND.

Comment: Yes ,you're right , Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is building an integer value whose decimal representation resembles the input value's binary representation.  I've heard of "Binary Coded Decimal", so I'll call this thing "Decimal Coded Binary."  Haha!

It's probably always better to manipulate binary representations as some kind of string value, not as an internally binary-encoded integer which happens to look like a binary representation of some value when converted to a decimal representation.  But, its sort of a fun to figure out how to go about doing things like this anyway.

Your `to_bin` function already worked, so I copied it below as `DecimalCodedBinary`.

To chop off the higher-order digits and keep the low N digits for a number represented in base B, you just need to get `X (mod B^N)` (where '^' is exponentiation).

So, for working with base 10, I made a special function, `Pow10` which returns 10 to the power of its argument.

And finally, the `LowDigitsDecimal` is a correct implementation of `get_last_n_digits`, returning `nr % Pow10(n_dig)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

unsigned long long DecimalCodedBinary(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned long long pow10 = 1;
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    while(n) {
        result += pow10 * (n % 2);
        n /= 2;
        pow10 *= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

unsigned long long Pow10(int exponent) {
    if(exponent < 0) return 0;
    unsigned long long pow10 = 10;
    unsigned long long result = 1;
    while(exponent) {
        if(exponent % 2) result *= pow10;
        exponent /= 2;
        pow10 *= pow10;
    }
    return result;
}

unsigned long long LowDigitsDecimal(unsigned long long nr, int count) {
    unsigned long long modulo = Pow10(count);
    return nr % modulo;
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long dcb_val = DecimalCodedBinary(254);
    std::cout << dcb_val << "\n";
    unsigned long long dcb_val_low_2 = LowDigitsDecimal(dcb_val, 2);
    std::cout << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << dcb_val_low_2 << "\n";
```

Answer (score 10):

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/JrNGXz)**

To read/select the bits at specific positions you have to hide, or mask, the rest of bits. One way to achieve this is the bitwise AND: the `&` operator (not the logical and, `&&`). Assuming that we are talking about an 8 bits number, if the input is 15 and the mask is 7, the result is 7:

```
Input:  decimal 15 as binary: 0000 1111 &
Mask:   decimal  7 as binary: 0000 0111
------------------------------------------
Output: decimal  7 as binary: 0000 0111
```

Your problem actually is to find the proper mask. If you’re asked for last 4 bits, your mask should be `0000 1111` (15 decimal, F hexa). If you’re asked for last two digits, your mask should be `0000 0011` (3 decimal, 3 hexa). Steps to find the mask for the last n bits:

1. Set all bits to 1. This can be done by negating zero: `~0` -> `1111 1111` (255 decimal, FF hexa)
2. Shift `n` bits to left: `~0 << n`. If n is 2, you will get `1111 1100`
3. Negate the result: `~(~0 << n)`. If n is 2, you will get `0000 0011`.

Once you have the mask, all you have to do is to use the bitwise AND:

```
output = input & ~(~0 << n)
```

This is what you'll get in the end:

```
unsigned get_last_n_bits( unsigned u, int n )
{
  return u & ~(~0U << n);
}
```

**Displaying** the result in binary base is not achievable using standard stream manipulators. You cannot write something similar to `cout << hex << number`: there is no `bin` manipulator. However, it can be displayed if the number is converted to `bitset`: `cout << bitset< width >( number )`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

unsigned get_last_n_bits( unsigned u, int n )
{
  return u & ~(~0U << n);
}

int main()
{
  cout << bitset<8>( get_last_n_bits( 254, 2 ) ); // displays 00000010
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
static inline long get_last_n_bits(long num, int nbbits) {
   return num & ((1L<<nbbits)-1);
}
```

and read more about binary representations and bitwise operations; you might even make the type of the `num` formal a template argument... then use `get_last_n_bits<long>` or `get_last_n_bits<uint64_t>` etc..

then test that `get_last_n_bits(245,2)` is 1.

Your terminology is wrong, a digit is not a bit, or you should say a *binary digit*

Comment: Just to say that we recently had a bug because we haven't use `1L<<nbbits` for a long word. It might be safer to add a qualifier for the type of the constant?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your answer correctly (and I'm not sure I do; please clarify) you can use shifts to solve this:

```
int get_last_n_digits(int nr , int n_dig)
{
    int shift = (sizeof(nr) * 8) - n_dig;
    return (nr << shift) >> shift;
}
```

The first shift (left) clears all unwanted bits, the second one puts the wanted ones back into place.