# Grabbing 'n' binary bits from end of unsigned int in C? Bit masking?

Tags: c, binary, hex, bit, bitmask

I'm pretty new to C and I seem to be messing up my bitmasking. From what I understand, it's a way to grab or create something of a subset from a binary value.

Say I want to grab the last 8 bits of an unsigned int value, containing 00001111000011110000111100001111.

How would I use AND/OR to grab those last 8?

Comment: what have you tried so far ? where are your C code attemtps ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get last n bits of binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942546/get-last-n-bits-of-binary)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more general solution to generate the mask based on how many bits you're interested int.

```
unsigned int last_n_bits(unsigned int value, int n)
{
    unsigned int mask = -1;
    if (n < sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT)
        mask = ((1<<n)-1);
    return value & mask;
}
```

Comment: you should `assert` that `n < sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT`

Comment: and then you've got a problem getting all bits.

Comment: The width of unsigned might technically be less than `sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT` as there could be padding bits, but dealing with that efficiently would lengthen your answer for little practical benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BINARY AND operator for do a binary mask:

```
unsigned char last_eight_bits = my_number & 0b11111111
```

Comment: No need for the bit operation if the target is a `char` (or another type that is (usually) 8 bits wide). Also 8 times 1 is harder to count than two times f.

Answer (score 0):

Mask-out all bits `> 0xff`:

```
value & 0xffu
```

Comment: Or create a mask using `(1 << 8) - 1` where 8 represents the number of bits to grab (beware not to exceed the size of the integer, of course).

Answer (score 0):

> Say I want to grab the last 8 bits of an unsigned int value, containing
> 00001111000011110000111100001111.
>
> How would I use AND/OR to grab those last 8?

In this case, you would use AND. The following code will grab the 8 least significant bits:

```
unsigned int number = 0x0F0F0F0Fu;
unsigned int mask = 0x000000FFu; // set all bits to "1" which you want to grab
unsigned int result = number & mask; // result will be 0x0000000F
```

The `&`-Operator is used for an AND-Operation with each bit:

```
    00001111000011110000111100001111
AND 00000000000000000000000011111111
------------------------------------
    00000000000000000000000000001111
```

Be aware that "0 AND X = 0" and that "1 AND X = X". You can do further investigation at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra.